How Do I End My Powershell Regex Syntax Torture?
I want a Powershell regex replace command to convert strings such as these...
RedHerringFallacy
SunkenCostFallacy
FalseDilemmaLogic
AnyOtherCamelCapString

to...
Red_Herring_Fallacy
Sunken_Cost_Fallacy
False_Dilemma_Logic
Any_Other_Camel_Cap_String

Here are all my unsuccessful attempts:
1) The Lookbehind
$string = "FundRegions"
$modifiedString = $string -replace '(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', '_'  
$modifiedString

Gives me: F_u_n_d_R_e_g_i_o_n_s
2) Plain and Simple
$string = "FundRegions"
$modifiedString = $string -replace '([a-z])([A-Z])', '$1_$2'
$modifiedString

Gives me: F_un_dR_eg_io_ns
3) There's No Going Backticks
$string = "FundRegions"
$modifiedString = $string -replace '([a-z])([A-Z])', '`$1_`$2'
$modifiedString 

Gives me: `F_`u`n_`d`R_`e`g_`i`o_`ns
4) One Character at a Time
$string = "FundRegions"
function InsertUnderscores([string]$str) {
    $result = ""
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $str.Length; $i++) {
        $result += $str[$i]
        if ($i -lt $str.Length - 1 -and $str[$i] -match '[a-z]' -and $str[$i+1] -match '[A-Z]') {
            $result += '_'
        }
    }
    return $result
}

$modifiedString = InsertUnderscores $string
$modifiedString

Gives me: F_u_n_d_R_e_g_i_o_n_s
Calgon, take me away! Please help. Thank you.

You should state the problem clearly. "My powershell regex syntax torture" and "i want to convert strings such as these to this" tells us nothing. My interpretation is you want to  separate with underscore based on capitalization. Since you don't actually state it, it's just a guess. You should immediately understand that by default powershell regex is case insensitive. Check the linked duplicate and then look up the different regex operators such as cmatch, creplace, etc.

I'll take a shot at it, case sensitive replace.  I delete the _ at the beginning after.  Most of what you did would work with -creplace or -cmatch, except the backticks which have to be in double quotes.
(echo RedHerringFallacy SunkenCostFallacy FalseDilemmaLogic,
  AnyOtherCamelCapString) -creplace '([A-Z])','_$1' -replace '^_'

Red_Herring_Fallacy
Sunken_Cost_Fallacy
False_Dilemma_Logic
Any_Other_Camel_Cap_String

Or in one step with negative lookbehind for beginning of line:
(echo RedHerringFallacy SunkenCostFallacy FalseDilemmaLogic,
  AnyOtherCamelCapString) -creplace '(?<!^)([A-Z])','_$1'


Yes, both you and the poster after you suggested -creplace. Never knew about it. Thanks to you both!
